# Types of set screws for glass shower door handle

Tags: doors, shower, glass, sliding-glass-door

I'm trying to tighten up a loose shower door handle. However, I'm having trouble removing the set screw and can't figure out what type of driver I need. I've tried flat head, philips and allen, but nothing seems to turn the fastener.

It's also an incredibly awkward place to get a good look at. What types of set screws are common for shower door handles

[image]

Comment: I think you just need a hook wrench (there's no set screw)

Comment: I think that's a divot that you can hook to unscrew. Maybe try a hex key for leverage.

Comment: Or plastic jawed pliers...

Comment: Was able to twist it with a hex key, thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there another hole on the other side? not required, but they are often in pairs. This looks like a spanner (or pin spanner or hook spanner) bolt, where that hole is just where the wrench hooks in to rotate the part; not an Allen wrench (or Robertson or Torx) setscrew at all. I don't see any sign of a setscrew from the image.

[image: Pin or hook spanner image from canadianhobbymetalworkers.com]

Given the use, that would make sense - a setscrew would probably corrode to uselessness in short order in that application.